# storcli - not able to import raid array

Tags: raid1, storcli

I have a set of 2 disk drives which were configured into a Raid 1 array and working fine. I set them offline and removed them for offline storage.

When I insert them they originally show as UBAD and I can change them to UGOOD. Then then appear as a UGood F and there is no virtual drive for them showing up in the status list (see 62:0 and 62:4):

```
PD LIST :
=======
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model            Sp Type 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
62:0     10 UGood F  9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:1      8 Onln  0  9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:2      4 Onln  0  9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:3      5 Onln  0  9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:4      9 UGood F  9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:5      2 Onln  0  9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:6      0 Onln  0  9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
62:7      3 Onln  0  9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`storcli /c0/fall import preview` returns the following preview:

```
FOREIGN PREVIEW :
===============
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT     Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID1 OfLn  N  9.094 TB dflt N  N   dflt N      N  
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID1 Dgrd  N  9.094 TB dflt N  N   dflt N      N  
 0 0   0   62:4     9   DRIVE Offln N  9.094 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
 0 0   1   62:0     10  DRIVE Offln N  9.094 TB dflt N  N   dflt -      N  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Yet `storcli /c0/fall import` complains that `Incomplete foreign configuration`.

Is there a way to get this array to recover? I would like to be able to reliably recover these arrays when they are swapped out. A prior attempt on this with a different pair worked fine and the drive immediately came up on the host.

I have tried `storcli /c0/e62/s0 set online` but that complains that `Operation not allowed`.